# Airflow deferred operator example: Where are BaseTrigger and TriggerEvent from?

Tags: python, airflow

I am attempting to try using Deferrable opertators however, the example seem to be lacking info on where `BaseTrigger` and `TriggerEvent` are imported from. I cant seem to find info on the docs too

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/deferring.html?highlight=triggerevent

```
    def __init__(self, moment):
        super().__init__()
        self.moment = moment

    def serialize(self):
        return ("airflow.triggers.temporal.DateTimeTrigger", {"moment": self.moment})

    async def run(self):
        while self.moment > timezone.utcnow():
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        yield TriggerEvent(self.moment)
```

- Is `BaseTrigger` the same as [`airflow.models.trigger.Trigger`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/trigger/index.html#airflow.models.trigger.Trigger)?

Comment: These classes were introduced in Apache Airflow version 2.2.2. In 2.1.2 they are absent. So check the version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BaseTrigger` is located in `airflow.triggers.base.BaseTrigger` and `TriggerEvent` is located in `airflow.triggers.base.TriggerEvent`.

An IDE such as PyCharm is very helpful in finding such things: press [double shift](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/05/when-the-shift-hits-the-fan-search-everywhere/) and search `BaseTrigger` will get you to module directly.

Comment: Just wondering, so this information is only discovered by either a better IDE or view source? Isit not in some documentation somewhere?

Comment: I agree the example code isn't very complete without the imports so I've made a PR to update the docs: https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/24544/files

Comment: Clarification is always good. I merged the PR.